# Adding a value to an existing column based on values in two other columns including a partial match

Tags: r, string, conditional-statements, match, partial

I'm sure this is easy but it's getting on my nerves, and I can't find a single answer.
I have a dataframe with a number of columns. One column "Accepted_Taxon_Level" is partially populated and I would like to *add* a value to otherwise empty cells in this column depending on the contents of two other columns.

Eg. if column Match.Point = "Autonym" AND column Name contains "var." somewhere in a string, then "variety" is added to column Accepted_Taxon_Level.

I was trying to use 'within' but cannot get it to match a subset of a string

```
        df <- within(df, Accepted_Taxon_Level[Status == 'Autonym' & Name == '*var.'] <- 'variety')
```

grepl was confusing me using multiple conditions and pasting into the destination cell without overwriting the existing contents.
Any help gratefully received!

Example input:

```
df <- data.frame('Status' = c('Autonym','Not Autonym','Not Autonym','Autonym','Autonym'), 'Name' = c('Something something var. something','Something else','Something else var. somethingother','Else else sub. else','Other other var. other'),'Accepted_Taxon_Level' = c('','species','variety','',''))
```

Example desired output:

```
df <- data.frame('Status' = c('Autonym','Not Autonym','Not Autonym','Autonym','Autonym'),'Name' = c('Something something var. something','Something else','Something else var. somethingother','Else else sub. else','Other other var. other'),'Accepted_Taxon_Level' = c('variety','species','variety','','variety'))
```

Comment: `within(df, Accepted_Taxon_Level[Status == 'Autonym' & grepl('*var.', Name)] <- 'variety') `

Comment: Ugh, I was all around it >.< Thank you!